# Return the largest value of selected columns in one row

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to do this using dplyr. I don't know if and how I could for example use `max.col` in dplyr syntax. Also, I don't see how I could get the index of the higher value with `apply(which.max())`
Below my attempt, but it seems not exactly concise. Also, it would become quite tedious with more than 2 columns. I have the feeling I am missing something very obvious.

```
foo_df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:4], val1 = 1:4, val2 = 5:2)

require(dplyr)

# the following gives the desired output
foo_df %>% mutate(max_val = case_when(val1 >= val2 ~ val1,
                                     val1 < val2 ~ val2))

  id val1 val2 max_val
1  a    1    5       5
2  b    2    4       4
3  c    3    3       3
4  d    4    2       4
```

Ties should be ideally be possible to handle in different ways such as "random" or "colx".

Comment: In base R, something like `cols = paste0("val", 1:2); transform(foo_df, v = do.call(pmax, mget(cols)))` though I have no idea what the dplyrish way is.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I hadn't found this one! Super helpful.

Comment: @MrFlick Would you suggest me to delete my question or leave it for search engine purpose?

Comment: @Frank Thanks , I wasn’t aware of pmax, it’s very interesting ! As per the answers to the question which MrFlick pointed out - pmax can also be used with dplyr::mutate :)